# Python: How to append a string to a scrapy list item?

Tags: python, list, class, parsing, scrapy

I'm scraping a collection of urls, but they all lack the base of the url, so I want to append the "start_url" as a base to each scraped url.

Spider class:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "teslanews"
    allowed_domains = ["teslamotors.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.teslamotors.com/blog"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        updates = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="blog-wrapper no-image"]')

        items = []
        for article in updates:
            item = TeslanewsItem()
            item["date"] =  article.xpath('./div/span/span/text()').extract()
            item["title"] = article.xpath('./h2/a/text()').extract()
            item["url"] = article.xpath('./h2/a/@href').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

I can't do a simple `item["url"] = article.xpath('./h2/a/@href').extract() + base` with `base = "http://www.teslamotors.com"`

because this adds the base to the end and it does it letter by letter due to being in a for-loop and each letter is separated by commas.

I'm relatively new to Scrapy so I don't exactly know which way to go with this.

Comment: Can't you do `item["url"] = base + article.xpath...` instead?

Comment: Nope. The result is `h,t,t,p,:,/,/,w,w,w,.,t,e,s,l,a,...` you get the point. This is due to being in the for-loop, so it goes character by character.

Comment: Nor can it be added in that same format outside the for-loop. Nothing happens.

Comment: I mean doing this code: `item["url"] = base article.xpath('./h2/a/@href').extract()[0]` . Sure it won't work?

Comment: By taking your recommendation and adding `+` between the two elements, it worked!

Comment: extract() returns a list, so you have to take the first element of the list ! And of course, I missed the `+` there lol . you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from urlparse import urljoin


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "teslanews"
    allowed_domains = ["teslamotors.com"]

    base = "http://www.teslamotors.com/blog"

    start_urls = ["http://www.teslamotors.com/blog"]

    def parse(self, response):

        updates = response.xpath('//div[@class="blog-wrapper no-image"]')

        items = []
        for article in updates:
            item = TeslanewsItem()
            item["date"] = article.xpath('./div/span/span/text()').extract()
            item["title"] = article.xpath('./h2/a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = urljoin(self.base, ''.join(article.xpath('./h2/a/@href').extract()))

        return items
```

Comment: @charles-watson did it help?